# JSON callfunction doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

here is my *example*

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + area.getCenter().lat + "," + area.getCenter().lng + "&sensor=false";

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    alert("inside json");
    //console.log(data);

    $.each(data.results[0], function (i, inside) {
        console.log(i);

    });

    //var addr = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;

});
```

now i realized that the call function doesn't fire at all....i read other post here and they say that it happens when JSON is not in valid format but here i am getting JSON from Google API so i hope its in valid format.... JSON is here

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=27.88,78.08&sensor=false

can you please give your comments on this? or may be i am making some mistakes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a full ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + area.getCenter().lat + "," + area.getCenter().lng + "&sensor=false",
        data: {},
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSON",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (Result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < Result.d.length; i++) {
                element = Result.d[i];
                console.log(element);
            };

        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi i tried this but nothing happened. I checked on firebug and the success: function (Result) doesn't goes inside..so it is not success....and then it goes to error function but doesn't show any alerts...any idea what should be next

Comment: Try changing the URL directly to :   url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=27.88,78.08&sensor=false". This should give you an indication if area.getCenter().lat and area.getCenter().lng are working correctly. This is just for testing, and what error does your console report?

Comment: Hi yes i changed it to direct url but again the same thing..so it means getCenter() is working. and surprisingly firebug doesn't throw any error , it silently comes out of error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        } without even touching the inner statement i.e alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
so my conclusion is firebug goes to success, but doesn't execute inner statement may be because its not success...again it checks for error but doesn't go inside..so it is bypassing everything..ok...so what should i do next..thanks

Comment: Try a different browser, and get fiddler: http://fiddler2.com/, this will help you understand the request being generated.

Comment: Looking at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/RdtMg/ it seems that there is an authorisation issue with the maps API (I get 405)

Comment: Hey i think its solved. I created a separate function and calling getJSOn from it. it works..but still couldn't identify why it wasn't working in the normal program flow..anyhow thanks a lot

Comment: All that counts at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

can you add it to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

for *example*:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + area.getCenter().lat + "," + area.getCenter().lng + "&sensor=false";

      $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
          alert("inside json");
          //console.log(data);

          $.each(data.results[0], function (i, inside) {
              console.log(i);

          });

          //var addr = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;

      });

  });
```